# java assignment regex

Tags: java, regex

Could you please provide regex to match assignments in the text

```
$one: 3-2; $three: 4-1; 4
$one: 3-2
```

I've tried `\$\w+:.+?;?` and expect it to match `$one: 3-2;` and `$one: 3-2`.
But it matches only `$one:`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
\$\w+:[^;]*;?
```

In java.

```
"\\$\\w+:[^;]*;?"
```

Your regex matches upto the first space it's mainly because of the non-greedy pattern and the following optional semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

```
\$\w+:.+?(?:;|$)
```

You need to use this with `multi line` mode. Yours is not working because `;` is optional and `.+?` is non-greedy so it will stop by consuming only 1 character as it has the option to ignore `;`

See demo:

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/8

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\$\w+:\s*([^;]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH2bI8/2)

In Java it will be:

```
"\\$\\w+:\\s*([^;]+)"
```

Comment: May I know the reason of downvaote?

Comment: The question is phrased like its a school assignment that isnt working. Possibly that's why your answer is getting downvoted because it seems like you're spoonfeeding.

Comment: Actually it didn't look like school assignment. I assumed OP is talking about variable assignment e.g. `$one: 3-2`.

Comment: You are correct, probably that's why the downvoter removed the downvote.